# Google Map API v3 OVER_QUERY_LIMIT not going away

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using Google maps for development of enterprise application for a large retail chain in India. Once the application goes in production it will use the Google map enterprise and will have their own key. Currently we are using the free version for development. With heavy testing activity for last 2 weeks we might have overshot the limit. We have waited for 3-4 days but the service has not restored.

There is no support / contact information on the page to help this part. Our account for Google map is with the gmail id locationgurudeveloper@gmail.com.

IP addresses where this is a problem are 223.30.43.149 and 175.41.143.188.

Can someone help to resolve this issue and get the service back on track?

Abhay Chaudhary

VP Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with Google. For the moment you can reverse geocode with a client-side JavaScript. In my opinion it works better.